# Custom CacheResolver for Redis Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

When using `spring-data-redis` caching annotations on a `spring-data-jpa` repository you can provide a `@CacheConfig` annotation with the `cacheResolver` property referencing a custom bean that implements `CacheResolver`. In this bean you can then amend the cache name that may have been specified in the `@Cachable` annotation. For instance we use this custom resolver to append the tenant name to the cache in our multi-tenant setup.

We now want to use Redis as a datastore in its own right, not just a cache. When specifying a POJO you want to be stored in Redis you are able to use the `spring-data-redis` `@RedisHash` annotation and provide a keyspace as the `value` property of that annotation. However, this is a constant value and does not seem to be able to be configured. It looks like the next version of spring-data-redis will allow SpEL expressions in the `@RedisHash`'s value property, but it is not clear if that will provide all the functionality we need.

Is there a `CacheResolver` type class that can be configured for `@RedisHash`s to allow for custom key space resolving?